# PHP Request URI containing multiple slashes gives internal error 500

Tags: php, url-rewriting, internal-server-error

I basically want to rewrite URLs using PHP. I built my script on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16389034/2532203).
Thinking about the design again though I decided to construct my URLs like this:

```
http://example.com/category/sub-category/page-name
```

Now when I try to use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, the apache server just throws an 'internal server error 500 - script error'. This only seems to appear if the requested URL contains more than one `/`-character.
How can I store the full path requested?

Comment: Open the server errorlog (of apache) and look why apache has thrown http 500.

Comment: This is a managed server, I got zero access to the server other than FTP

Comment: Contact your hoster for support.

Comment: To b honest, I expected something a bit more informative...

Comment: create a script that has just this:
<?PHP
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_SERVER);
echo "</pre>";
This will show you the server vars and gaive you a chance to see what's going on.